# Discriminating users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a blog, following Rails Getting Started tutorial and would like to publish it now. Though lots of actions  should not be visible to my visitors..

Such as :

- creating an article
- editing an article
- deleting a picture
- ...

When I went through the Rails Routing section http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html I have discovered that I could create routes for the Admin. But this means altering my code, or creating code especially for the User who has different rights than the Admin.

My questions :

- Is creating a specfic routing for the Admin is what's called  a "namespace" ? (I saw this
  "namespace" reference in some other questions)
- Will I need to duplicate controllers and create adhoc functions
  for the Admin ? (or restricted functions for the User as my current code has all functions already)
- In what respect some gems such as Devise, Pundit, ActiveAdmin would help me
  in that respect. And what are the differences between those gems?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understood, some users just shouldn't see some information or they can't doing some actions. Than I suggest you create roles for users:

user.rb

```
enum role: [:user, :admin]
```

and than just in view for example:

```
  = link_to 'EDIT', my_edit_path if current_user.admin?
```

or

```
  = link_to 'EDIT', my_edit_path unless current_user.user?
```

same you can do for actions:

```
redirect_to :roo_path and return if current_user.user?
```

[MORE ABOUT ENUM IN RAILS](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

**EDIT**

BTW

for `enum` you should have extra column, in your case it's `role`

Comment: Many thanks Oleg, this is exactly what I need. But when you say "creating roles" is it via Devise? Moreover I thought I would need to create proper controllers for th Admin but the hiding links technique you describe seems pretty good.